# How is $2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)(n+1)}=\frac{6}{4}$ calculated?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$$2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)(n+1)}=\frac{6}{4}$$
I cant figure out why this is $\frac64$. I try to use telescopic series without success.

Comment: It seems that you are aware this is a telescoping series, which is the major hurdle to solving this problem.  What exactly is it, then, that you're having trouble with?

Comment: i cant get that result

Comment: I think what you are missing is
$$\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1} = \left(\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$
So $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2}{(n-1)(n+1)} =\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{2-1} + \frac{1}{3-1} = \frac{3}{2}$$
Sometimes you need a little bit transform to bring your expression into standard telescoping form.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

$$\frac2{(n+1)(n-1)}=\frac{n+1-(n-1)}{(n+1)(n-1)}=\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n+1}$$

**Reference** : [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint :**
$$
\frac{2}{(n-1)(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}
$$
and a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 2):

Ok well first of all $\frac{6}{4}=\frac{3}{2}$.

The series telescopes as has been pointed out, using that formula we have

$$\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+
\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+
\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}\right)+
\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}\right)+\cdots =1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since OP is apparently aware this is a telescoping series, here's the computation.
$$
2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)(n+1)} = 
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(n-1)(n+1)}=
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) =\\
\left[ 
\left(1 - \frac 13\right) + \left(\frac 12 - \frac 14\right) 
+ \left(\frac 13 - \frac 15\right) + \cdots
\right] = \\
\left[ 
1 + \frac 12 + \left(\frac 13 - \frac 13\right) + \left(\frac 14 - \frac 14\right) + \cdots
\right] = \frac 32
$$

Comment: you forgot the $2$ at the beginning, sorry for being so tedious..

Comment: As I commented, I think the $2$ was put there in error

Comment: Check it again please

Comment: Ah, I see; a careless mistake.  Thank you for mentioning it.